# IE lan settings revert back when rpt open it during recording http proxy

Tags: ibm-rational

I am beginning to use Rational Performance Tester to do some load/performance testing and I stuck at the first step - recording a script. I am using IE 11 and I am disabling internet by going to Internet Options>Content>Lan Settings. Then I try to open some website and it won't open - which is good (expected behaviour). Then I run my RPT to do the recording and the Internet options revert back and 'Automatic Configuration' check box get checked (unwanted behaviour). The HTTP proxy recorder say that it is accepting connection at (some number) port but open connections stay 0. The bytes in the recording window do not move with any click, thus nothing being recorded. Thanks in advance!

I have only tried it in IE 11. Don't have access to any other browser (company policy)

There is no coding required.

I expect open connections to move above 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was solved when I had admin rights to the machine and application - run IBM RPT as administrator. Thus I was able to record the http traffic and successfully play it back using the load agents.